# Why does compiling C take so long time?

Tags: c, compilation, fpga, intel-fpga, nios

When I compile a C project it can take about 90 seconds even though I use a fast Intel I7 CPU. Is it because compilation is a low-level task or why are my build times so long? My environment is the Nios 2 IDE for Altera DE2 FPGA.

Comment: Depends on the size of your project. The Linux kernel can take several minutes. Really big projects like Gnome or LibreOffice up to hours.

Comment: Configuring cache options in the Makefile can help you to save time, but for small projects that you need to compile often, I recommend to use ramdrives. The compiler has to access the drive for each file and that takes time...

Comment: Compiling and synthesizing a FPGA project surely takes a long time:).

Comment: It is quiet normal for programs made for soft core processors to take longer than the ones for a hard core CPU. In many cases, the time for compile/link is not as much as the actual download of the code, re-start of the CPU, load the new SW and re-starting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your project is managed by Makefile, try "make -jn" to trigger mul-threads in compiling, n is thread num for compiling, e.x. "make -j10"

Answer (score 1):

Is it actually the compile taking the time?  My experience of softcore processor (and other embedded development) is that the compile is quick (comparable with compiling host-based code) and the time is taken uploading the new code to the embedded system to test.